# SharePoint 2010 - ActivityManager.GetActivitiesForMe issues

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I am experiencing some problems with the ActivityManager in SP 2010. I want to retrieve a number of events from my "feed". It seems like the GetActivitiesForMe method in the manager has support for taking a DateTime object as a parameter, which will act as a delimiter and return only events that have occured after that DateTime. This is exactly what i am looking for, but it does not seem to work.

This works great:

`GetActivitiesForMe();`

And returns events from the last 14 days(which seems to be a default-value).

This does not work:

`GetActivitiesForMe(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-25))`

This returns nothing, not even the items within the last 14 days.

Have anyone else bumped in to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is set through the MinEventTime property of the ActivityManager, if you pass in a date that is older than this it returns nothing.

Try something like this.

```
var manager = new ActivityManager(mySiteContext);

if (myDate <= manager.MinEventTime)
{
  myEvents = manager.GetActivitiesForMe(manager.MinEventTime);
}
else
{
  myEvents = manager.GetActivitiesForMe(myDate, this.MaxItemsToDisplay); 
}
```

Comment: That does work, but i still can't figure out how to override the default value of 14 days. Bug?